# Como colocar titulo no JDesktopPane?

Tags: java, swing, jdesktoppane

Estou desenvolvendo um software para uma videolocadora com design pattern MVC (Model-view-controller) com o Framework Java Persistente Api  e com a linguagem XML. A minha dúvida é o seguinte: Como coloca e edita titulo no `JDesktopPane`?

Exemplo:

[image: Foto da tela principal]

Queria mudar o nome de "singelo" para "sistema de videolocadora". Como faz isso?

Código- fonte da tela:

```
package formularios;
import classes_persistencia.AcessoDAO;
import classes_registros.Acesso;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import classes_utilitarias.AlteraFundo;
import classes_utilitarias.GravaPosicao;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;





public class FrmPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private AcessoDAO conexaoAcesso = new AcessoDAO();
    private Acesso registroAcesso = new Acesso();
    private ArrayList<Acesso> registrosAcesso = new ArrayList<>();

    public static int altera = 1;
    public static int elimina = 1;
    public static int insere = 1;
    public static int cadastroAtor = 1;
    public static int cadastroDiretor = 1;
    public static int cadastroGenero = 1;
    public static int cadastroFaixa = 1;

    private Date date = new Date();

    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaAgenda = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaCliente = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaTitulo = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaUsuario = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaFornecedor = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaCalendario = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaAtores = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaGeneros = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaDiretores = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaPrecos = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaRelatorios = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaLocacoes = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaConfig = new JInternalFrame();
    public static JInternalFrame enderecoJanelaDevolucao = new JInternalFrame();
    private static String caminhoFundo = "";

    public FrmPrincipal(String usuarioLogado, int nivelAcesso) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        initComponents();
        if(nivelAcesso == 4){

        }
        else{
            configuraAcessos(nivelAcesso);
        }

        File pasta= new File("c:/Singelo");
        File pasta1= new File("c:/Singelo/Imagens");
        pasta.mkdir();
        pasta1.mkdirs();


        add( mdi_principal, BorderLayout.CENTER );         
        FrmStatus status = new FrmStatus(usuarioLogado);
        mdi_principal.add(status);
        status.setVisible(true);

    }
```

Obs: `mdi_principal` é o `JDesktopPane` e `Frm_principal` é o `JFrame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O titulo da imagem apresentada é do `JFrame`. O método [`setTitle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle-java.lang.String-) é que altera o titulo do `JFrame` e, consequentemente, da janela:

```
setTitle("sistema de videolocadora");
```

Basta adicionar dessa forma no método construtor da sua classe `Frm_principal`.

Comment: Como faz para seta?

Comment: @IgorContini tem um comando na resposta, basta adiciona-lo na sua classe do JFrame.

Comment: Qual comando e como vou adiciona ele? Sou iniciante ainda...

Comment: @IgorContini veja se a edição melhorou a resposta.

Comment: Agora sim! Entendi e obrigado! :)